# Get Distinct String List From DataTable

Tags: c#

To reduce the amount of code, is it possible to combine this in one line - where I convert a DataTable column into a string list, but I only want the distinct items in that list (there are multiple columns, so sometimes columns will have multiple values, where one won't):

```
List<string> column1List = returnDataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x["Column1"].ToString()).ToList();
var distinctColumn1 = (from distinct1 in column1List select distinct1).Distinct();
```

The above works, but is an extra line.  Since the distinct is an option on the list, I did try:

```
List<string> column1List = (returnDataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x["Column1"].ToString()).ToList()).Distinct();
```

However, that errors, so it appears that distinct can't be called on a list being converted from a DataTable (?).

Just curious if it's possible to convert a DataTable into a string list and only get the distinct values in one line.  May not be possible.

Comment: Simply move `Distinct()` **before** `ToList()`. FYI, `Distinct` is an extension method of `IEnumerable<T>`, not a method of `List<T>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Distinct` returns `IEnumerable<TSource>` in your case it  returns `IEnumerable<String>` and you are trying to get the `List<String>` in the output.

You need to change the code from

```
List<string> column1List = (returnDataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x["Column1"].ToString()).ToList()).Distinct();


List<string> column1List = (returnDataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x["Column1"].ToString()).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `System.Linq` you can use something like this

```
my_enumerable.GroupBy(x => x.Column1).Select(x => x.First).ToList()
```